# What are the properties of the options object passed to queryInterface.removeConstraint()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

The documentation for [queryInterface.removeConstraint()](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-removeConstraint) doesn't document the `options` object that can be passed to the `removeConstraint()` method. In fact, none of the `options` objects that can be passed to the various `queryInterface` methods have been documented...

Is the `options` object documented anywhere?

Versions:

- Sequelize: 5.21.3
- sequelize-cli: 5.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the document should be improved. This is a confirmed issue [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11856). If you are using TypeScript, you can find the interface of this `options` in the [query-interface.d.ts](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/types/lib/query-interface.d.ts#L101) file.

Here are the interfaces for `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`:

```js
/**
   * Removes constraints from a table
   */
  public removeConstraint(tableName: string, constraintName: string, options?: QueryInterfaceOptions): Promise<void>;
```

```js
/**
* Most of the methods accept options and use only the logger property of the options. That's why the most used
* interface type for options in a method is separated here as another interface.
*/
export interface QueryInterfaceOptions extends Logging, Transactionable {}
```

```js
export interface Logging {
  /**
   * A function that gets executed while running the query to log the sql.
   */
  logging?: boolean | ((sql: string, timing?: number) => void);

  /**
   * Pass query execution time in milliseconds as second argument to logging function (options.logging).
   */
  benchmark?: boolean;
}
```

```js
export interface Transactionable {
  /**
   * Transaction to run query under
   */
  transaction?: Transaction;
}
```